# Can I place vias under components if they're not on the pads?

Tags: pcb-design, surface-mount, routing, via, signal-routing

There are several posts on this site (and elsewhere) discussing why, in general, vias on pads need to be avoided.

Understood.  Can I place vias under components if they're not *under the pad*?

If so: Is it better to place them on the edge of the component or in the middle? My intuition is that it may be better mechanically not to disrupt the edge with any change, but perhaps I'm wrong?

Does it matter if the component is SMD, plug-in, or through-hole?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never experienced issues with vias under components, and have seen thousands of commercial boards that do exactly this (including the ones I've designed).

In fact with larger BGAs you essentially have no choice but to use vias next to pretty much every ball (so under the component), because there is no room to route out the traces any other way.

Comment: Thanks.  Does it matter if they are completely under the component, or under the edge (partially under, partially outside)?

Comment: Personally I try to avoid vias partially under smaller surface mount components, as you can sometimes get odd surface tension effects with melted flux during reflow, which stops them centering properly on their pads.  

However, if routing choke points give you no choice, I wouldn't have an issue doing it.